# How to create the IPAs only without connecting a device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, testflight

I don't have a device but my manager ask to upload a **build** on testflightapp Is there anyway so that I can  create **IPA** and upload my build without having real **device**?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. you can do that..but you will need a developer account to deploy apps for Ad-hoc or App store Distribution ..

Edit : To upload the build ...just Archive the app with the provisioning profile..and upload the ipa to testfilght.

Comment: can you explain it in bit detail i am new to setting up certificates and provisioning profiles

Comment: when i go to edit scheme ->archive  give build configuration-> adhoc distribution(which i made) now when i go to product-> archive(this archive is unclickable or disabled)

Comment: you have to choose iOS device right next to scheme dialog...not a simulator..then archive option will be available

Comment: i have selected iOS device but still result is same not archive available.I think this is because i dont have any device attach to my mac

Comment: true thing is it you should be able to archive without the device...the problem you are facing is not because of no device attached..it might be something else..lots of possibilities...i suggest you see some youtube tutorials on uploading iPhone app to app store..then come back here and see the answers

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "Upload build" in TestFlight there's a link to a help page which answers your question: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4

Otherwise, for the first part of the tutorial, if you're in an Xcode version in which you don't have the Entitlements option, you can safely skip that part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

off-course you can do that, make your adhoc certificate then follow the procedure mentioned in your developer account. For uploading on testflight build the binary and put in Payload folder and then compress that folder and rename that compress file to appName.ipa
If you have any query I will be happy to help.

Comment: can you explain in detail i am new to setting up profiles and certificates?

Comment: login to developer.apple.com and follow this https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

Comment: If any more query let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html) from Apple. It should explain everything you need to know about code signing, certificates and making the IPA file for Ad Hoc distribution.